# Table or Grid with expandable and collapsible column

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, ios7, android-widget

I am trying to create a table where the first column can be expanded or collapsed to a predefined with in both iOS and Android. Any tips on code for this? Are there open source widgets out there can do this?

[image: First column expanded by default]

[image: First column minimized by finger slide]

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Just to confirm - this would work for the horizontal table like view I have and also note that when the first column collapses - it doesn't completely collapse... It just collapsed to a new width.

Answer (score 1):

Try `RATreeView` for IOS.

Git Url - https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView.